# getting the list of class having the properties from two different tables

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have two different entities,

```
class Department
{
    int DepID;
    string DepName;
}

class Emp
{
    int Empid;
    string Empname;
    int Empage;
    int EmpDep; //id of department
}
```

and I am getting the list of Emp with DepName using the join in Linq, and I want to directly assign this values to datagrid.

So my question is how to get the data converted into list and what will be the object type of this list.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
employees.Join(departments, e => e.EmpDep, d => d.DepId,
    (e,d) => new EmpView { EmpName = e.EmpName, DepName = d.DepName }).ToList()
```

where I use a type `EmpView` to bind to the grid. (This way, you can make a method that produces EmpViews and another method - or component - that does the databinding, separation of concerns).

Comment: Did a minor edit because I mixed up anonymous type syntax with object initializers.

Answer (score 2):

The resultant type will be an anonymous type. I don't think you can directly convert resultant List to a particular type of List unless you have explicitly defined that type.

So if you will put `.ToList()` at the end of query you will get list of anonoymous type in a `var` type object.

Why you need the strong type here? You can just set data grid item source equal to list you got from LINQ

Comment: Thanks Haris, but is there any way I can get the list in which the object of list contains the property of both the class?

Comment: yes you can by using select statement in LINQ query. Something  like this  `select new {instance1.Property1,instance2.Property2 and so on };`